# Long term behavior of the solution of $y''+\omega_0^2y=\cos(\omega t)$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes

Please consider the differential equation $$y''+\omega_0^2y=\cos(\omega t)\;,\;\;\;\omega_0,\omega\in(0,\infty)$$
I've actually calculated the general solution $$y(t)=\begin{cases}c_1\cos(\omega_0t)+c_2\sin(\omega_0t)+\frac{1}{\omega_0^2-\omega^2}\cos(\omega t)&\text{, if }\omega_0\ne\omega\\ c_1\cos(\omega t)+\left(c_2+\frac{t}{2\omega}\right)\sin(\omega t)&\text{, otherwise}\end{cases}\;\;\;,\;\;\;\;\;c_1,c_2\in\mathbb{R}$$ Now, I would really like to make a point on how the long term behaviors of these solutions differ. Since the involved trigonometric functions don't converge, it doesn't seem to be sensible to consider $\lim_{t\to\infty}y(t)$.

Obviously, the crucial point is that for $\omega=\omega_0$ resonance occurs and one would expect that the solution diverges to infinity.

Comment: The transient solutions tend to die out so what is the steady state response of the system?

Comment: True in general, but this ODE has no damping, so there is no transient response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now, I would really like to make a point on how the long term
> behaviors of these solutions differ.

For $\omega\not=\omega_0$ (i.e. the system is not at resonance), $y(t)$ is the sinusoid of constant amplitude in your explicit solution, and hence is bounded. The system's response is bounded oscillation of constant amplitude.

On the other hand, when $\omega=\omega_0$ (i.e., the system is at resonance), the lower branch of your explicit solution demonstrates that you get a sinusoidal response with a linearly increasing amplitude, so $\limsup_{t\to\infty}|y(t)|=\infty$.

Comment: Why does $y(t)$ "tend to the sinusoid of constant amplitude" if $\omega\ne\omega_0$?

Comment: Is your question on the "tend to" part or the "constant amplitude" part? It tends to that function, because it *is* that function! And it certainly has a constant amplitude.

Comment: I don't get it. $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ oscillate as $t$ tends to $\infty$. Could you please show how you determine $\lim_{t\to\infty}y(t)$ if $\omega\ne\omega_0$?

Comment: "Now, I would really like to make a point on how the long term behaviors of these solutions differ." This is how they differ: when the system is not at resonance, you get the bounded oscillations in the first branch. When the system is at resonance, you get the unbounded oscillations in the second branch.